# Not getting email notifications from MySQL Server

Tags: cron

**MySQL inf:**

**Protocol Version**: 10
 **Version**: 5.1.73
 **Version_compile_machine**: x86_64
 **Version_compile_os**: redhat_linux_gnu

**Problem**: I use crontab to run a backup script on mysql server every night. After that backup runs, I get an email. I have been receiving emails for months but all the sudden they stopped 2 days ago.  Backup runs every night successfully, but I am not getting emails. Crontab job has not been changed.

How do I send a test email from mysql server to check if emails can be sent?

Would the following place show me the logs for any email errors?
/var/log/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for this question. Have you opened the link that the cron runs directly on the browser to see if there's errors?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am new to this site, so I am not sure where I should post this questions. This is a MySQL error, posted on a MySQL tag.  Can you provide a link to where I should post this question?

Comment: The email is not sent by the MySQL server. It is sent by the cron daemon and it contains the output of the cron script.

Comment: Does anyone has any ideas about this issue in CRONTAB or CRON sections?